# How to downgrade dependency version of a package in dotnet6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nuget-package, downgrade

I am working on a .net6 project and using Automapper version 12.0.0.0 in one of the class library(say BusinessLayer), which is working fine.

Now when I add another locally developed (Say Package1) nuget package which has Automapper dependency as >=10.1.1 in the BusinessLayer class library then this Pkg1 package adds Automapper dependency with 12.0.0.0 version. However, this Package1 package is not compatible with Automapper 12.0.0.0 version. How can I downgrade the Automapper dependency of a Package1 to 10.1.1?

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Package1" Version="4.0.1" />
```

[image]

Can someone help me downgrade the Automapper dependency of a pkg1 to 10.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace its version as such.

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
```

Comment: This will replace parent level Automapper version to 10.1.1 too. I don't want that. I just want to downgrade dependency of Package1 and leave the parent level Automapper with 12.0.0.0